# PDF reader supporting "next document in the folder" keyboard shortcut?

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf

In Sumatra PDF you can skip to next document in the current folder by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right/Left</kbd>. I am looking for an alternative PDF reader available in Ubuntu that supports this feature.

Comment: Would be a relevant feature allowing you to skim through a pile of PDF's, just like you can quickly move to the next photo in a graphics viewer. Not supported in the default PDF viewer evince, and i am not aware of a viewer that would support this.